# Custom Post Type has wrong label and is not found when called by a loop

Tags: custom-post-types, php, theme-development, loop

I'm new to WordPress (and to code), having just started my classes. I am working on a project with a few students and can't find a way to call my Custom Post Type.

I tried several solutions from StackExchange, but I can't really find a solution for my problems.

**Problem 1 : my custom Post type doesn't have the right name in my back office**

Here's how I coded my custom post type :

```php
function custom_post_type_bateau() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => 'Bateaux',
        'singular_name'      => 'Bateau',
        'menu_name'          => 'Bateaux',
        'name_admin_bar'     => 'Ajouter',
        'add_new'            => 'Nouveau bateau',
        'add_new_item'       => 'Ajouter un bateau',
        'edit_item'          => 'Modifier un bateau',
        'view_item'          => 'Consulter un bateau',
        'search_items'       => 'Chercher un bateau',
        'parent_item_colon'  => 'Bateaux parents',
        'not_found'          => 'Aucun bateau n\'a été trouvé',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'Aucun bateau n\'a été trouvé dans la corbeille'
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => 'Bateau',
        'description'        => 'Un bateau de SailingLoc',
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'bateau' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'menu_icon'          =>'dashicons-paperclip',
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
    );

    register_post_type( 'bateau', $args );
}
```

I called it in my functions.php :

```php
add_action('init', 'initialisation');

function initialisation(){
    //activation des menus dans le backoffice
    register_nav_menus();
    //creation d'un custom post type bateau
    custom_post_type_bateau();
    // activation des images à l'affiche
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
}
```

Problem is that the name displayed in my back-office isn't "Bateaux" but "Articles".

[image: Backoffice screenshot]

**Problem 2 : I can't call the post-type bateau**
So I made a page to display my post-types. I called it with this WP Query :

```
<?php
    $query = new WP_Query([
        'post_type' => 'bateau',
        'posts_per_page'=>15
    ]);
?>
<?php
    $the_query = new WP_Query();
    $the_query->query($query);
; ?>
<div class="gp3">
<?php /*BOUCLE QUI RECUPERE LES DERNIERS POSTS*/
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
        $cpt = 0;
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
?>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="fiche-bateau">
            <div class="image-bateau">  
                <div class="product-thumbnails image-responsive"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-title"><?php the_title('<h3>', '</h3>'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php 
    $cpt ++;
    if ($cpt%3 == 0) :
?>
</div>
<div class="gp3">
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <p>Rien à afficher</p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

The variable $query should link to the custom post-type 'bateau' but doesn't. Instead I get the blog posts.

Could you help me pretty please ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the labels in problem 1 is that you haven't passed the labels to `register_post_type()`. You've defined the labels in the `$labels` variable, but this is what you passed to `register_post_type()`:

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => 'Bateau',
    // ...
);

register_post_type( 'bateau', $args );
```

You need to pass the `$labels` array:

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    // ...
);

register_post_type( 'bateau', $args );
```

---

For problem 2, your problem is that you're trying to pass a `WP_Query` instance to another `WP_Query`. `$query` needs to just be the array of arguments, but you've passed an entire `WP_Query` object:

```
<?php
    $query = new WP_Query([
        'post_type' => 'bateau',
        'posts_per_page'=>15
    ]);
?>
<?php
    $the_query = new WP_Query();
    $the_query->query($query);
; ?>
```

That needs to be just:

```
<?php
$the_query = new WP_Query ( [
    'post_type'      => 'bateau',
    'posts_per_page' =>15
] );
?>
```

*But*, you shouldn't need to create a page or template like this at all. In your post type registration you have:

```
'has_archive' => true,
```

This means that an archive (list) page for your post type is created automatically at `http://example.com/bateau/`. This is what the "Voir les articles" link in the admin bar in your screenshot is linked to. If this isn't working, make sure to go to *Settings > Permalinks* to flush your permalinks (visiting the settings page is enough), and make sure that your theme's templates are properly using the main loop:

```
if ( have_posts() ) : 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    endwhile;
endif;
```

Note the lack of `$the_query->` and any `new WP_Query()`.